# display an image named after as the username of the logged in user in PHP

Tags: php

i have uploaded some pictures manually in a folder : images

Let's say : 1.jpg , 2.jpg , 3.jpg ...
If 1,2,3 ... were the unique usernames of my users..

i'd like some help in PHP code on how to call that image when
for example USER: 1 is logged in, 
so as to display it on his profile.

Thanks

Comment: You'll get as much help as the amount of code you've supplied. Please supply your code (your attempt) to show us where you're having difficulties.

Comment: `WHERE user='Bobby Joe'`................ `{ // show image }` - Yeah, it's unclear and broad, just like the question.

Answer (score 0):

if user is logged in then get `user_id` from session. And if your session in already set then,

```
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
```

**Footer**:

If all images are in `jpg` format then,

```
<img src="<?=$user_id?>.jpg" name="user_pic" />
```

**PS:** As you haven't showed your code, we can't help you that much. Please do some work by yourself.